# Postgresql Cast to JSONB[] for each row in trigger?

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-factory

I need help to cast a column value to JSONB[] for each row.
Ther column name is 'data' and the incomming datatype is text. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_to_jsonb_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.data := CAST(data as jsonb[]);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_cast_for_each_row
   BEFORE insert
   ON public."ObjectSource"
   FOR EACH ROW
       EXECUTE PROCEDURE cast_to_jsonb_function()
```

what is wrong?
Thanks in advance

***Update***

I try to send the data from Azure Data Factory via a sink operation. The error: `ERROR: column "data" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[] Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

The error is described here:

```
Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink23': Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO public."T_6706_e42793586b044e378bcfb67ea5c046ac" ("id","createdAt","data","r2b7e32e69df34f3da6c55150166c5d5b") VALUES (1,'2023-08-23 +00','{"{\"sourceexpression\":\"^P\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"^P000\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"^P000_KLAUS2\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"P000_KLAUS22\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"^P\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"^P000\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"^P000_KLAUS2\"}","{\"sourceexpression\":\"P000_KLAUS22\"}"}',1) was aborted: ERROR: column "data" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 138  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

My landing database (defintion):
[image]

Comment: Where does `data` come from? It is an undeclared variable in your function.

Comment: "*the incomming datatype is text*" - I doubt that. Can you show the table definition and the insert query, please?

Comment: I cannot think of any good reason ever to use `jsonb[]`, but that is not what you are asking.  Please try this:  `NEW.data := array[data]::jsonb`

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/zDtcH9Mh). Maybe the Azure Data Factory Sink thing is using a different syntax than the error message contains? Either way, a trigger will not help here (unless possibly this is a `VIEW` with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger?). The problem is with the `INSERT` statement. Get rid of the trigger.